# TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByTagName(...).click is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, onkeydown

[Origin source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752813/listening-to-the-keypressed-event-razor/36753358#36753358)

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        // 37 is left arrow, 39 is right arrow
        if (e.which === 37) {
            document.getElementById('previousPhoto').getElementsByTagName('a').click();
        } else if (e.which === 39) {
            document.getElementById('nextPhoto').getElementsByTagName('a').click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

generates an error which I put on the title above.

P.S. There are those links. Working perfectly when I mouse-click.

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of elements, and it does not have a `.click()` method. You could use a loop, or just grab the one at index `[0]`, but it will be cleaner if you use `querySelector` instead. `document.querySelector("#previousPhoto a").click()`

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` gets a nodeList, an array-like list of all the matching elements.

If you want the first element in that collection, you'd access it with `[0]` etc.

```
document.getElementById('previousPhoto').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
```

For IE8 and above, `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` is available as well

```
document.querySelector("#previousPhoto a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with array of nodes and trying to click it. You must use index to access the specific element and then click.

`document.getElementById('previousPhoto').getElementsByTagName('a'[0]).click();`

Another way to get the child anchor tags of the element `previousPhoto` you can use `querySelector`

`document.querySelectorAll('#previousPhoto a')[0].click()`